# Main content on homepage missing from time to time?

Tags: magento-1.9, home-page

For no particular reason the main content of my shops homepage is missing. The footer and header are still there. I am not running any extra cache, just the basic Magento stuff.

I have no idea where to look. When I clean the Magento cache, it starts working again.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Thanks!

Comment: Please check it by disabling cache type "Blocks HTML output "

Comment: It was disabled already, so that is not the reason I guess?