# Homepage intermediately not working Magento 2

Tags: magento2, home-page

Similar to  [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182509/main-content-on-homepage-missing-from-time-to-time)  sometimes my homepage shows the 404 page not the homepage. I know that in the admin side it's linked correctly, because most of the time the homepage shows up. All the caches are enabled on the magento side, and I also use cloudflare. I am also using the pearl theme.

Edits based on comments:

What the homepage looks like when this error happens:
[image]

Browser console log:

[image]

Server error log:

from the 22nd : client denied by server configuration

Magento debug log:

from the 19th : main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate

So it is some kind of caching issue, but I have no idea what is causing it.

Comment: provide more information. we an't help with what you provided. specify "sometimes"

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what's causing it. It's happened maybe 3 times this week? I've been doing a lot of work on it, so I'm not sure what's triggering the change. If I flush the cache it'll come back, so I think it's a caching issue which is why I mentioned what catching I was using.

Comment: we can't help you like this

Comment: Is there some logs I could look to help or would a screenshot help? I'm willing to do digging and edit my question, I just don't know where to start.

Comment: Please do provide your server log and magento log, error messages in browser console as it will be helpful

Comment: I will do that the next time it happens, thanks!

Comment: I have updated this question with logs + screenshots